# changing background of internet site with javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

So, i wanna make button on my site(html). With clicking button u could change the background of the site. I wanna make function of that in *.js file. Any suggestions or ideas how to do it are welcome.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and the we'll help you

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: `onClick="document.getElementById('IDOfTheElementWithBackground').style.background = '...';"`

Comment: Im total newbie at javascript, knowing only few commands :S

Comment: break it into pieces: 1) how to find your button with js 2) how to bind a click event to it 3) how to change the background. These are things that should be pretty easy to google. Give it a shot! :)

Comment: I'm sorry but if you are a "total newbie" Stack Overflow is not the place to polish your skills. Go grab a book, experiment a little. At least try.

Comment: Ibstr i know the 1 and 2 point, the 3rd one is where i am stuck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="changeBackground()" value="Change Backgorund" />
```

JS

```
function changeBackground(){
$("body").css("background","url('pathtoimage')");
}
```